# Postgres how to insert reals with decimal comma?

Tags: postgresql, decimal-point

My database is a postgres v14 database with en_US UTF-8 locale. I have to import many .csv files and they have usually a decimal point (3.14) for reals and sometimes a decimal comma (3,14). My question: is there a way to set postgres in such a way that the data are correctly read into postgres?

What I did: I know whether the data has a decimal point or comma. In pandas the solution is rather elegant by setting the locale, like:

```
# test for decimal point, set locale accordingly
decimaal_teken = meta_data.iloc[0].loc['bronbestand_decimaal']
if decimaal_teken == '.':
    logger.warning(f'Floating point met decimale punt')
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'en_EN.utf8')

elif decimaal_teken == ',':
    logger.warning(f'Floating point met decimale komma')
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'en_DK.utf8')

else:
    logger.warning(f'Onbekend decimaal teken: "{decimaal_teken}", decimale punt wordt gebruikt')
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'en_EN.utf8')
```

I am looking for a similar solution in postgres but I cannot find it. I have a test file that looks like:

```
SET lc_numeric = 'en_DK';
-- SET DECIMALSEPARATORCOMMA=ON;

INSERT INTO public.floats (naam, value)
VALUES
('Drente', '112,5');
```

I import the file in psql either by -f  or \i . In both cases there is an error that 112,5 is not a valid real. 112.5 is accepted.

The DECIMALCOMMASEPARATOR I found in [this article](https://docs.actian.com/psql/psqlv13/sqlref/sqlref.SET_DECIMALSEPARATORCOMMA.htm) yields an error when importing the file in psql. I have set the linux locale to en_DK as well but no success.

I can replace the comma by a dot but I want to leave the data untouched. I cannot imagine that postgres has no solution for this. Can somebody help by pointing me to some information I overlooked?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number literals always have to use a decimal point, no matter how `lc_numeric` is set. This parameter only influences how the format letter `D` (among others) is interpreted by `to_numeric()`:

```
SELECT to_number('112,5', '990D99');

 to_number 
═══════════
     112.5
(1 row)
```

You can use that with `INSERT`, but you won't be able to use it with `COPY`.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. If I understand you correctly: postgres has not a single provision to read real's with decimal comma's, though a lot of users must read those numbers. They all have to convert the comma to a period (either in SQL or somewhere else)?

Comment: That is precisely correct.